# URLEncoder with POST method in Android

Tags: android, http-post, httpurlconnection, urlencode

I am trying to put data from my android application into PHP file on a web server to be used to make a query from MYSQL server.

I was trying the below command to encode the variable before sending it as I saw a lot of programmer used it on the internet.

Edit: I edited my Android Code to split the String into two segments and concatenate it but I still receive nothing in the PHP variabe.

New Code:

```
if (operator.equals("GetRow")){
            try {
                String selectedcoresite = params [1];
                URL url = new URL(rowsurl);
                HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);

                OutputStream OS = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
                BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(OS, "UTF-8" ));
                String key = URLEncoder.encode("selectedcoresite","UTF-8");
                String value = URLEncoder.encode(selectedcoresite,"UTF-8");
                String data = key+value;
                bufferedWriter.write(data);
                bufferedWriter.flush();
                bufferedWriter.close();
                OS.close();

                InputStream IS = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(IS, "iso-8859-1"));
                while ((line2 = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                    row+= line2;
                }
                bufferedReader.close();
                IS.close();
                httpURLConnection.disconnect();
                return row;



            }catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
```

where the "selectedcoresite" is the key and selectedcoresite in second statement is the variable.

the error with me is that android refuses the command allowing me only to do only one statement without +.

```
URLEncoder.encode(Name, "UTF-8");
```

this causes the PHP file not to recognize its input as it depends on the key "selectedcoresite" to put the value.

what should I do?
PHP Simple Code:

```
<?php
require "init.php";
$coresite = $_POST["selectedcoresite"];
echo json_encode($coresite);
```

thanks

Comment: Strange story. But you can use several statement with += to concatenate strings. Or use + String("=") +.

Comment: Do you mean to separate both encoding commands in different statements then concatenate the string?

Comment: Never used operator `+=` on strings ?

Comment: yeah .. I'm new to programming .. just two weeks :) .. thanks at any case I modified the code on your way but it didn't work

Comment: "It didnt work" is not a good description for others. Showvw the code you tried.

Comment: I made an edit and posted the full code of this POST operation, but the PHP variable $coresite still not receiving data from my app. the php returns error "missing index" for the $coresite variable.

Comment: `String data = key+value;` Didnt you forget something? `key + "=" + value`.

Comment: Great, I am really thankful, the POST worked by this and also by String Buider and appending data with "=" .. I didn't know that "=" is a part of the encoded data. much appreciated Greenapps :). now I stucked in the PHP code after receiving the data .. seems that I need to read more about how to print the sent variable or insert it in a new query. I would be thankful if you can give me a topic to read in this point.